# UINavigationItem animation

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create custom animation for `UINavigationItem`. I have navigation bar with 4 items, but when I scroll down I want to put search bar in navigation. I would like to have animation bottom-top, but everything I tried is not working.

Here are some stuff I tried:

- `setLeftBarButtonItem:animated:` (it is working, but it is jerky - not fluid at all. Kinda looks like gif...
- UIView with: animation,delay, option, hanlder, almost every method from UI for animations ( not working at all)

I should also note that I have one button and search bar in navigation after scroll.

My question is - Is it possible to change default animation and make my own? And, if so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: It is a little hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Please could you add some screenshot or illustration of what you want. Also, post the code you have tried.

Comment: I don't have mac here so I can't show you the code, but what I want to achieve is pretty simple. On button click, or scroll or any other event, I want to change navigation bar elements with custom animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do exactly, but you could place a custom view into `leftBarButtonItem` and animate it however you want (you'll need to implement touch handling in the view, though)...

Depending on the animation you need, you could use a `UIScrollView` as the custom view and set it's `contentOffset` depending on the `contentOffset` of your views scrollview (creating a similar effect as the Twitter app uses when viewing a users main page).

I tried the first method (custom view with animations) and it seems to work quite nicely:

```
class itemView : UIView {
    var active : Bool {
        set {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
                if newValue {
                    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.1415/2)
                } else {
                    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-3.1415/2)
                }
            })
        }
        get {
            if let color = backgroundColor {
                return color.isEqual(UIColor.greenColor())
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I then used it like this (I'm changing the active state with a simple event handler, linked from the `rightBarButtonItem`, but you can use just about anything here, including `scrollViewDidScroll:`):

```
let item = itemView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    item.active = false

    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(customView: item), animated: false)
}

@IBAction func itemClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    item.active = !item.active
}
```